# HighChart setoptions color issues in IE

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, highcharts

I am creating pie chart using HighChart. The pie chart coming properly in FF, chrome but in IE it is picking up wrong color code for chart.

Used custom colors.

```
Highcharts.setOptions({
     colors: ['#CC0099','#F00000','#339999','#FF6600','#66CC33','#006633','#FFCC33','#FF9900','#9966CC']
    });
```

Does Internet explorer need any changes for Highchart library?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tested [this](http://jsfiddle.net/sbochan/S4Dxj/show) example and `colors` looks like the same in Chrome / FF / IE8. Which browser do you use? Have you the newest highcharts ?

Comment: I am using IE8 and Highcharts JS v3.0.1 (2013-04-09)

Comment: Please update my exampel with your code, and update to 3.0.2.

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes it happens in IE but there is an issue of IE because jQuery is a framework of Javascript it not properly work in IE and highchart is in jQuery so you can solve this problem through custom edit by inspect element in IE by F12
hope it may help you